# Default list of Django built-in middleware

Tags: django, sorting, settings, middleware, built-in

Django comes with a [list of built-in middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/), but if one wants to use all (or most) of them, he has to work through tons of docs in order to get the right sorting in the settings.py file.

Is there an optimal default order of *all* built-in Django 1.1 middleware classes? I.e., something to copy'n'paste into settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  # perfect order here please ;-)
)
```

Alternative answer: Are there multiple possible orderings and what would be the difference?

By the way: The order *is* significant, but I'm only aware of some of the default dependencies, like SessionMiddleware before AuthenticationMiddleware.

Comment: Are you looking for how to order _all_ the available middleware at the same time (that is, using all the available middlware together) ?

Comment: Yes, in short. I figure the Django developers would have a prefered order, if they'd use all their own middleware, and I'd like to know that order.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632323/how-to-perfectly-sort-django-middleware

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do have a [default list](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware) for the core Django middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
```

Any other ones that you create or get from third parties can be added at the end of the tuple above.  The Django book also mentions that on a view request, the order is from `CommonMiddleware` to `AuthenticationMiddleware` and finally to your view.  On a return response, the order is reversed from `AuthenticationMiddleware` to `CommonMiddleware`.  Here's the [doc](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter17/#s-middleware-installation) for it.

**In response to the comment:**

After scouring the Django tickets, it looks like this has been a know issue with the Django dev community and I don't think there is a final answer to it yet.  Here's the [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/730#comment:34) which contains the discussion along with the part where Jacob closed it down. You might want to try to bring that issue again as a Django ticket to get an official dev response.

Comment: yes, I know, but the list is missing django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware, django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware and so on, which are *already included* in Django by default. My question is, how the *default, built-in* middlewares could be arranged.