# Practical rules for Django MiddleWare ordering?

Tags: django, django-middleware

The official documentation is a bit messy: 'before' & 'after' are used for ordering MiddleWare in a tuple, but in some places 'before'&'after' refers to request-response phases. Also, 'should be first/last' are mixed and it's not clear which one to use as 'first'.

I do understand the difference.. however it seems to complicated for a newbie in Django.

Can you suggest some correct ordering for builtin MiddleWare classes (assuming we enable all of them) and — most importantly — explain WHY one goes before/after other ones?

here's the list, with the info from docs I managed to find:

1. `UpdateCacheMiddleware`

   - Before those that modify 'Vary:' `SessionMiddleware`, `GZipMiddleware`, `LocaleMiddleware`
2. `GZipMiddleware`

   - Before any MW that may change or use the response body
   - After `UpdateCacheMiddleware`: Modifies 'Vary:'
3. `ConditionalGetMiddleware`

   - Before `CommonMiddleware`: uses its 'Etag:' header when `USE_ETAGS=True`
4. `SessionMiddleware`

   - After `UpdateCacheMiddleware`: Modifies 'Vary:'
   - Before `TransactionMiddleware`: we don't need transactions here
5. `LocaleMiddleware`, One of the topmost, after SessionMiddleware, CacheMiddleware

   - After `UpdateCacheMiddleware`: Modifies 'Vary:'
   - After `SessionMiddleware`: uses session data
6. `CommonMiddleware`

   - Before any MW that may change the response (it calculates ETags)
   - After `GZipMiddleware` so it won't calculate an E-Tag on gzipped contents
   - Close to the top: it redirects when `APPEND_SLASH` or `PREPEND_WWW`
7. `CsrfViewMiddleware`

   - Before any view middleware that assumes that CSRF attacks have been dealt with
8. `AuthenticationMiddleware`

   - After `SessionMiddleware`: uses session storage
9. `MessageMiddleware`

   - After `SessionMiddleware`: can use Session-based storage
10. `XViewMiddleware`
11. `TransactionMiddleware`

    - After MWs that use DB: `SessionMiddleware` (configurable to use DB)
    - All `*CacheMiddleWare` is not affected (as an exception: uses own DB cursor)
12. `FetchFromCacheMiddleware`

    - After those those that modify 'Vary:' if uses them to pick a value for cache hash-key
    - After `AuthenticationMiddleware` so it's possible to use `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY`
13. `FlatpageFallbackMiddleware`

    - Bottom: last resort
    - Uses DB, however, is not a problem for `TransactionMiddleware` **(yes?)**
14. `RedirectFallbackMiddleware`

    - Bottom: last resort
    - Uses DB, however, is not a problem for `TransactionMiddleware` **(yes?)**

(I will add suggestions to this list to collect all of them in one place)

Comment: MessageMiddleware needs to be after SessionMiddleWare because the message framework *can* use a session-based backend for storing messages.

Comment: This should be a Community Question as there can be no single person with a single correct answer :) however, I see no checkbox

Comment: I agree that the terminology is confusing.  Perhaps 'inside' and 'outside' would be more appropriate.  Those listed closer to the beginning of settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES are 'outside;' those listed closer to the end are 'inside.'  This matches the graphic depiction in the django docs, and also represents the fact that middleware, when executed, can set up an environment **within which** subsequent middleware would operate.

Comment: Why this question doesn't have hundreds more stars and upvotes, I'll never know! Thanks!

Comment: Django changed quite a lot in two years time, any pointers to an identical, but more *recent* resource? Thanks, +1ed.

Comment: Maybe [SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most difficult part is that you have to consider both directions at the same time when setting the order. I would say that's a flaw in the design and I personally would opt for a separate `request` and `response` middleware order (so you wouldn't need hacks like `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` and `UpdateCacheMiddleware`).

But... alas, it's this way right now.

Either way, the idea of it all is that your request passes through the list of middlewares in top-down order for `process_request` and `process_view`. And it passes your response through `process_response` and `process_exception` in reverse order.

With `UpdateCacheMiddleware` this means that any middleware that changes the `Vary` headers in the HTTP request should come before it. If you change the order here than it would be possible for some user to get a cached page for some other user.

How can you find out if the `Vary` header is changed by a middleware? You can either hope that there are docs available, or simply look at the source. It's usually quite obvious :)

Comment: [Django 1.10 splits separates request and response setups using the new `MIDDLEWARE` approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#new-style-middleware)

Comment: I tried every order in middleware, but as you say user two gets the cached result meant for user one and any new change in the database table is not reflected in the cache, it keeps using the same old unexpired cache. I have posted my problem here, can you help?? pleaseee..i have struggling for quite some time now [https://stackoverflow.com/q/70320750/8315427](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70320750/8315427)

Answer (score 2):

One tip that can save your hair is to put TransactionMiddleware in such place on the list, in which it isn't able to rollback changes commited to the database by other middlewares, which changes should be commited no matter if view raised an exception or not.